# Java convention in practice - return mutliple values from method

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I have two questions about Java Convention. I try to make use od Robert C. Martin's "Clean Code".

Following case:

```
public void startProgressIfAllowed() {
    try {
        tryStartProgressIfAllowed();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // log error
    }
}
private void tryStartProgressIfAllowed() {
    if (isStartProgressAllowed()) {
        stopProgressOnCurrentlyStartedTask();
        startProgressOnThisTask();
    }
}

private boolean isStartProgressAllowed() {
    // Calls JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog with JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION.
    // Created dialog contains checkbox indicating that saving currently started task is required.
    // returns boolean depending on JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION clicked button
} 

private void stopProgressOnCurrentlyStartedTask() {
    // Saves currently started task depending on checkbox selecion property and stops currently started.
    // What is the correct way to get checkbox selecion property?
}
```

Proposed solution:

```
public void tryStartProgressIfAllowed() {
    if (tryToStopProgressOnStartedTaskIfNecessary()) {
        startProgressOnThisTask();
    }
}

private boolean tryToStopProgressOnStartedTaskIfNecessary() {
    // Calls JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog with JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION.
    // Created dialog contains checkbox indicating that saving currently started task is required.
    // Depending on checkbox selecion property saves task.
    // returns boolean depending on JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION clicked button
}
```

1. But this approach doesn't meet the "Command Query Separation" principle, because tryToStopProgressOnStartedTaskIfNecessary(...) method performs some logic and returns success/failure value.
2. I think this approach also doesn't meet the "One level of abstraction per function" principle, because I suppose "check" and "save" operations are on different levels of abstraction.
3. Is the method name correct to avoid disinformation? Maybe better name would be tryToStopProgressAndSaveStartedTaskIfNecessary(...)?

Is there any better solution for above problem?

Comment: seriously? `tryToStopProgressAndSaveStartedTaskIfNecessary()` is a very very unprofessional name

Comment: The first thing I was told while I was in the University is that Java Conventions use long names. I must say that you overdid it!

Comment: I would simply call it `stopProgress` and put the rest of the story in javadoc. Reads an awful lot faster.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a long name, but according to "Clean Code" descriptive method name is much better than short and undescriptive (requiring javadoc comment) even if it's too long.
What about the solution and listed principles?

Comment: @geert3 I already have stopProgress method in my real code... :D But I try to make methods possibly small and this approach cause division one long method for many small (<=5 lines) with similar name. To distinguish these methods I must use such long descriptive names.

Comment: I agree that names must be meaningful, not like `public void a()`, `b()`, `c()`. But tell me how less meaningful `stopProgress` is vs `tryToStopProgessIfNecessary`. The second seems to hint that it will return gracefully if the thing can't be stopped or isn't running, as opposed e.g. to throwing an exception. The short name doesn't say that but you could tell the same from the presence/absence of a try/catch block.

Comment: I udpated above code to explain "try" prefix.
@geert3 You I probably right that "IfAllowed" suffix is unnecessary, but throwing exception in this case is in my opinion inappropriate, because it's normal case, no an error. 
What about listed priciples? What do you think about moving exception handling to seperate method by adding "try" prefix" as I did?

Comment: The problem is not the name itself, it's the fact that the method does to much. If you feel the need to include "and" in your method name, it probably does too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following:

```
public void tryStartProgressOnThisTaskIfAllowed() {
    tryStopTaskInProgressIfAllowed()

    if (!isTaskInProgress()) {
        tryStartProgressOnThisTask();
    }
}

private void tryStopTaskInProgressIfAllowed() {
    if (!isTaskInProgress()) {
        return;
    }


    TaskInProgressResult result = whatToDoWithTaskInProgress();
    if (result == Result.KEEP) {
        return;
    } else if (result == Result.DROP)
        tryDropTaskInProgress();
    } else if (result == Result.SAVE) {
        trySaveTaskInProgress();
    }
}
```

About your points:

1. You now have two separate methods for C and Q
2. I think the two things `whatToDoWithTaskInProgress` and `tryDropTaskInProgress` are the same level of abstraction. If you'd inline the code of one or the other you were absolutely right of course.
3. I changed some of the method names according to my taste :) The only thing I still don't like is the part "OnThisTask" because this task is somewhat meaningless. Maybe it's only because the rest of the code is unknown maybe OnNextTask or OnNewTask are better.

The problem we were having is that we were thinking in UI terms YES/NO + checkbox value. But it is much better to think in business terms here. I identified three different outcomes that are of interest: KEEP, SAVE, DROP How the answer is obtained should not matter to the calling method.

Comment: Ah I missed you problem to some extent: The qustion to the user can have three outcomes KEEP, SAVE and DROP. I am updating my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This seems something to ask on CodeReview, see the drop down at the top left of the page.

An example of how such stateliness is realized in Java SE: the regex Matcher class.

```
String s = ...
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("...");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, ... m.group(1) ...);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

with `m.matches()` and `m.lookingAt` as alternative circuits too.

In short state is held in a processing class on the actual data (String here).